# Is there a way to recover formatted hard disk with Windows when using Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-7, 17.04

I installed Ubuntu on my PC and by accident it formatted my whole hard drive. I can pick the hard drive up with Windows and everything but its basically formatted. Is there a way I can restore it using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use `Testdisk` for this purpose. https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhWbSM-630E

I am a real beginner in this topic. Once I lost my partitions while playing with `windows diskpart` and `Testdisk` helped me out.

I recommend you to boot your PC with a USB stick. As far as I know this prevents data loss, because your OS might be writing on the Disk and by doing so, overwrite some data.

Comment: Assuming the beginning of the partition has been overwritten `testdisk` may not work (but it is still a good first thing to try, in case the old partition layout was different and you haven't overwritten the start of the important one).  In this case photorec (by the same developer) will be able to recover some files but not all.